# Error in paper showing internal inconsistency in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In a recent [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-05739-8.pdf), “Quantum theory cannot consistently describe the use of itself”, D. Frauchiger and  R. Renner  describe a modified Schroedinger's Cat *gedankenexperiment*, in which there are two boxes (A and B), containing observers (Oa and Ob).  Observer Oa does a quantum measurement to obtain a 1 or 0 result.  He sets the spin of a particle up or down, corresponding to 1 or 0 respectively, and sends the particle to Ob.  Ob measures the spin of the particle and records the result.

In the meantime, there are two external observers outside the boxes, Ea and Eb.  Ec measures the state of the whole box A, while Eb measures the state of the whole box B.  All of the observers are assumed to know how the experiment is set up. The authors of the paper assert that the measurements made by Ea and Eb do not always agree, and that therefore quantum mechanics is internally inconsistent.

It seems to me that there may be a fundamental error in the reasoning described in the paper.  The error would be in the assumption that Oa can send a particle, whose state accurately reflects the state of Oa, to Ob.  It seems that this would amount to a violation of the no-cloning theorem in quantum mechanics, because in essence the sent particle's quantum state would be a clone of the quantum state initially measured by Oa.

I'd be grateful if someone in the PhysicsSE community could shed some light on this.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Comment: No cloning doesn't stop you from cloning orthogonal states - its stops you from cloning the whole state.

Comment: from their abstract "This  indicates  that  quantum  theory  cannot  be
extrapolated to complex systems, at least not in a straightforward manner" Sure , *not straighforward,* why does he think that quantum field theory developed on the substrate of quantum mechanics and the whole package of density matrices.

Comment: on mixing two agents: imo they are ignoring that any observation involves an interaction and a change in boundary conditions, i.e. a change in the wavefunctions describing the system.

Comment: In that paper, if Oa measures heads, then they prepare the spin in $|\downarrow \rangle$, but if they measure tails they prepare $|\downarrow \rangle + |\uparrow \rangle$. They do **not** *"set the spin of a particle to up or down"* as is written in the question posted here.

Comment: @annav Did you actually read the paper? The authors are not being so silly as to ignore mixed states and wave function collapse. At least, if they are, I haven't been able to tell yet (because the paper is unusually difficult to follow due to unnecessarily convoluted notation).

Comment: @DanielSank No I did not read it carefully, As an experimentalist I evaluated their proposal from the abstract and the introduction, and I would never expect a nested quantum mechanical experiment to be predictive in a non probabilistic fashion. Probability 1 happens with careful conditions  anyway in a single system. (That is why I just give an opinion and not an answer)

Comment: @annav In that case I would respectfully recommend against comments that suggest you *have* read the paper. For example, you write *"...why does he think that quantum field theory developed on the substrate of quantum mechanics and the whole package of density matrices."* That suggests that you read the paper and formed an opinion that the paper's author were somehow ignoring the existence of QFT and density matrices.

Comment: @DanielSank I am commenting on what they say in the abstract, I give the quote from the abstract. Unless you think they count  field theory as a simple! procedure

Comment: Just glanced at the paper, but I find it quite suspicious that: 1) one of the more prevalent concept there is 'agent', which is, as said in the abstract, are "themselves using quantum theory." 2) the end of the paper deals with "analyses" based on different (but quite specific) quantum interpretations, including QBism which is where we find the "agent" again. It seems to me that the focus of this work is more on the consistency of QM interpretations than on consistency of QM itself. By the way, certainly thermodynamics "cannot describe the use of itself" either... why should QM do so?

Comment: I am specifically interested in how the "no cloning" theorem would apply to this *gedankenexperiment*.

Comment: The paper seems to have made a fatal mistake in its treatment of a two qubit system. It has nothing to do with the no-cloning theorem, they simply use the (okay,okay) state to infer the spin directly but that state belongs to a different basis and thus can't be used for that direct inference. More specifically, this is a variant of Hardy's paradox and the classical inferences made by the observers in full certainty are flawed. See Scott Aaronson's analysis here: https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=3975

Comment: See this video for a nice walkthrough of the argument https://www.video.ethz.ch/speakers/its/2018/autumn/colloquium/cfedb640-b52e-41cc-9260-5819220cd6f6.html